# PHP gmp_mul() Error: Unable to convert variable to GMP - wrong type

Tags: php, gnu, gmp

I'm using PHP gmp functions.

I want to do the following mathematical statements:

```
$profit_percent = 2405.665;
$bill_line['purchase_average_value'] = 36000000000;   

$r = (1 + ($profit_percent / 100));
$r2 = $bill_line['purchase_average_value'];
$unit_price_with_profit = gmp_mul($r, $r2);
```

But the following error occurs:

> gmp_mul(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - wrong type

Comment: If I want to use decimal numbers in this function
what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see the description for the [GMP library](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.gmp.php):

> These functions allow for arbitrary-length integers to be worked with using the GNU MP library.

You are trying to pass a floating number to `gmp_mul()`. That will fail always.